# Validate File before getting uploaded using h:inputFile and javax.servlet.http.Part in JSF

Tags: java, validation, jsf, jsf-2

I am working on a *JSF* web project which uses the **h:inputFile** facility to upload files.I bind the value of h:inputFile to the backing bean property of type **javax.servelt.http.Part**

```
<h:inputFile id="inputfile" validator="#{bean.validateFile}" value="#{bean.part}"/>
```

Also I use the following file validation strategy in the same backing bean:

```
 public void validateFile(FacesContext con, UIComponent comp, Object value) {
    Part p = (Part) value;
    List<FacesMessage> list = new ArrayList<>();
    if (p.getSize() == 0) {
        list.add(new FacesMessage("File Size too small"));
    }
    if (p.getSize()>MAXSIZE) {
        list.add(new FacesMessage("File Size too Big"));
    }
    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        throw new ValidatorException(list);
    }
}
```

My Question:
  Does using **Part** interface cause the whole file to get uploaded to server side and *THEN* it get validated (i.e its size) on submitting the form?

As I experiencing it in a local host(Glass fish v.4), I see a message in the the left corner of my Chrome browser indicating the file upload progress and after that in case of file validation error I get the validation message.I worry in real situations(like slow internet connections),it is pretty an inconvenient way to send the size validation error after uploading the file!

Please help me, and if this is the case as I assume send the alternative solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal behaviour. The server needs access to the file to validate it (content, size...), and the access can only be granted through user interaction, e.g. form submitting.

See : [ICEFaces inputFile getting the file content without upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729110/icefaces-inputfile-getting-the-file-content-without-upload)

Comment: is there any possible way to get at least the file size on client side (i.e. using client side technologies) before committing the actual upload?